# Delphi Grid DrawColumnCell can not clear

Tags: delphi, datagrid, draw

I am following examples to put a checkbox in a delphi column cell. I can place a checkbox image in a cell. But the underlying boolean value is longer than the image so the checkmark is over the first two letters of "True" or "False". How can I clear the rectangle in the column cell? I tried printing the original "True" or "False" in no color, or white on white, but the text is always Black no matter what choice I make.
Sample of my code:

```
procedure TFUpdtLists.TreatGridDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State:  
TGridDrawState);
begin
  with Column do begin
    //  TreatGrid.DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);  ???
    if FieldName = 'Repro' then begin
      Canvas.Brush.Color:= TreatGrid.Color;
      Canvas.FillRect(Rect);//fails to clear cell, clears another area??
      if Field.Value = True then
        //#7 a checkmark and # 5 a blank image in the image list:
        MainView.ImageList1.Draw(TreatGrid.Canvas,Rect.Left,Rect.Top,7)
      else  
        MainView.ImageList1.Draw(TreatGrid.Canvas,Rect.Left,Rect.Top,5);
      TreatGrid.DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);//??
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In order to debug this, you could temporarily change the fill color to e.g. clRed so you will see what FillRect actually does.

Comment: Why are you calling DefaultDrawColumnCell? Surely you only want to do this if FieldName is not 'Repro'? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you should do DefaultDrawColumnCell only when the FieldName is 'Repro'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to the `Canvas` you refer to in the code when you paint the background. Since there is no argument called `Canvas` and also `Column` doesn't have a `Canvas` it refers to the `Canvas` of the `TFUpdtLists` executing the code.

You have already corrected the code for the `mageList1.Draw()` methods and added the grids reference (`TreatGrid`). Do the same for the bg painting.

It appears you have tried calling `DefaultDrawColumnCell()` in different ways, but you should call it only for the columns that you don't draw yourself.

Let me also suggest that you quit using `with ...` because it prevents code completion from working and it makes debugging harder as well as increases significantly the risc of coding errors.

With the above mentioned changes the `OnDrawColumnCell()` procedure looks like this;

```
procedure TForm19.TreatGridDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
  DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  if Column.FieldName = 'Repro' then
  begin
    TreatGrid.Canvas.Brush.Color:= TreatGrid.Color;
    TreatGrid.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    if Column.Field.Value then
    //#7 a checkmark and # 5 a blank image in the image list:
      Form19.ImageList1.Draw(TreatGrid.Canvas,Rect.Left,Rect.Top,1)
    else
      Form19.ImageList1.Draw(TreatGrid.Canvas,Rect.Left,Rect.Top,0);
  end
  else
    TreatGrid.DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
end;
```

You will want to correct the image indexes, which I changed to suit my imagelist in my test.

[image]

Comment: Perfect. A lesson in being cautious using broad "with" statements.  I experimented with many things, all doomed because as you said "pay attention to the canvas you refer to.."